# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'string' access Div in Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, data-access

I'm going to access my Div in Server side then I need to bind data to that div

My Code:

```
 <div id="leftpanel" class="panel-body" runat="server">
                </div>
```

Server Side code:

```
public void GetLeftPanelData()
{
    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
    leftpanel.InnerText = da.GetLeftPanelData(); // <-- Error Shown here
}
```

Data Access Method

```
public DataSet GetLeftPanelData()
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand comGetLeftPanelData = new SqlCommand("SP_GetLeftPanelData", con);
        comGetLeftPanelData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comGetLeftPanelData);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        throw ee;
    }
}
```

My Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetLeftPanelData]

AS
BEGIN
select Description 
from dbo.CommonPages
where Type= 6
END
```

Here is returning encoded HTML
![enter image description here][1]

In this query just returns 1 line of strings Like "Hello test data"

Comment: Do you have a question? The error is pretty clear.

Comment: how to solve this issue ?

Comment: So let's think about this, by setting the `InnerText` of an object (type of `string`) to a `DataSet`, what would you **actually** expect it to do?

Comment: I wanted to get data & put ti to the leftpanel div

Comment: @TechGuy, okay, so just setting the text of a `div` isn't going to inherently do that right? I'm trying to get you to think through this problem. You'd need some type of control that knows what to do with a `DataSet` right? I mean a `DataSet` isn't HTML right?

Comment: @TechGuy is it not allowed to use a `GridView` to display data?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I have some text in my database.I need to get that data & put it to a div.Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @TechGuy: yes there are ways to do this. A `GridView` is one of those ways. But what I'm trying to get you to work through is this. If I gave you a basket of apples and asked you to make apple pie, would you just throw all of the apples into a pie pan? No, you'd have to translate that **input** to get the desired **output.** Think about this when programming. You can't just set the text of a `div` to some input and expect that input to *just work.* Make sense?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud In here i just need to bind a data to div.gridview is not suited for this i think..Because i decorate outside the div to match with my site.Can i return(get) String type data from the DataAccess method.. then i think i can put directly to the Inner Html know ? am i correct ?

Comment: @TechGuy You need to iterate through your DataSet and output the data as a string of HTML.

Comment: @Wayne can please give me a answer ?

Comment: @TechGuy It's entirely subjective as to how you want to display the data within the DIV. Are you trying to get a table? If so, I would just recommend using a GridView as has been suggested, and pumping the data into it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish as your end result...?

Comment: @TechGuy Is your SQL query simply going to be returning you one row, with one column, with a lump of what you want to feed into the DIV?

Comment: @Wayne Yes this dataset consist only a 1 row of data

Comment: @TechGuy That only answers part of the question. It's one row of data, but is it also only one COLUMN? What does the data look like that you are returning? Please add to your question with a sample of what the query returns.

Comment: @Wayne Question updated.

Comment: @TechGuy It's lovely that you edited the question to show your query, but your query does not specify columns, it just says `select *`. This doesn't help me. I don't have any more information that I did before. As I asked previously, please add a **sample of the returned data**.

Comment: @Wayne question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that what I'm seeing in your updated question is correct, I would suggest using `ExecuteScalar()`.

This is used when you have a query that only returns a single piece of data. In this case, it looks like your query only returns a single row, with only the column Description. If that is correct, you could then do something like this:

```
public string GetLeftPanelData()
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand comGetLeftPanelData = new SqlCommand("SP_GetLeftPanelData", con);
        comGetLeftPanelData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        string returnData = (string)comGetLeftPanelData.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        return returnData;
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        throw ee;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use this method (I advise not to), change your method to this:

```
public string GetLeftPanelData()
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand comGetLeftPanelData = new SqlCommand("SP_GetLeftPanelData", con);
        comGetLeftPanelData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comGetLeftPanelData);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        return ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        throw ee;
    }
}
```